# Creating a dropdown menu for product categories Infusionsoft shopping cart

Tags: css, e-commerce, infusionsoft

Is there a way to alter the CSS on the Infusionsoft storefront so that it displays subcategories in dropdown?

Nicole

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in IS for this, but you can make one from scratch in the Header section of infusionsoft.